# Web server talking to multiple persistent processes

Tags: web-applications

I will first describe the functionality I want to achieve, then what I think my technical problems are.

Functionality: I want to create an HTML/JavaScript client for the IGS (Internet Go Server). It's similar to FICS (Free Internet Chess Server) in that playing is done via telnet, and all graphical clients are just wrappers around that original protocol. My goal is to be able to play without any additions to the web browser (no Java, Flash, etc.).

Technical issues: the biggest issue I see is server-side. In order to start a game, the web server has to open a persistent socket to the IGS, and use it to both send and receive data. (And every player will need a new such connection.) This is quite different from the CGI mindset used in web development.

One solution I thought of is the web server forking a process for each player that will manage the socket and talk to the web server via a DB. This doesn't sound very appealing (indirection, polling, ugh...). Hence my question: what is the standard solution to such a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) ([java version](http://code.google.com/p/socketio-java/)) for sending messages between a client and server over http.  You would need some sort of [message bus](http://www.zeromq.org/) to communicate moves between clients.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this means the browser has to run Java? If yes, then it's exactly what I *don't* want to do.

Comment: Sorry, no. Socket.IO can use various methods and fall back to supported features.  Possible transports are WebSocket, Adobe Flash Socket, AJAX long polling, AJAX multipart streaming, Forever Iframe,
JSONP Polling.  If WebSocket or Flash aren't enabled, ajax long polling should work.

Comment: D'oh, I clicked on all your links but the most important one :-) still, socket.IO works when talking between the browser and a web server, correct? I can't just open a socket to an arbitrary server (unless it supports socket.IO's transport model, which IGS doesn't). However, it appears I can fork off processes which talk with a real socket to IGS, and with socket.IO to the browser, skipping the web server altogether (except for the process forking). Is this what you meant?

Comment: After a short test, everything works great. Don't even need to fork processes, as node.js keeps all the sockets open. Thanks!